# Append jquery textarea ckeditor not workingg

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code. In this ckeditor function not applied to append data. I am using cdn link for ckeditor in header.php file. So how can I apply.

```
<script>     
   $(document).ready(function(){ 

        var i = 1;
        $('#add').click(function()
        { 

          $.getScript("ckeditor.js");

      i++;
      $('#dynamic_fields').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Title</label><input type="text" name="title[]" id="title" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control name_list"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Description</label><textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="desc[]" id="desc" rows="6" style="width:50%;" value=""></textarea><input type="hidden" name="imageid" value="">  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Product Image</label><div class="form-group"><input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple"></div></td><td><button name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" >X</button></td></tr>');

    });
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(){

    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
    });
   });

  </script>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code and even better make a snippet

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working. I have changed the place of your i++ to after the append and used the CDN for that js code and appended a counter to you ID because you can only have. I have tried this on my local machine and works without any errors. I am guessing this is what you wanted to do.

```js
var i = 1;

$('#add').click(function() {

  $('#dynamic_fields').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Title</label><input type="text" name="title[]" id="title" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control name_list"><label class="col-md-3 control-label">Description</label><textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="desc'+i+'" id="desc'+i+'" rows="6" style="width:50%;" value=""></textarea><input type="hidden" name="imageid" value="">  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Product Image</label><div class="form-group"><input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple"></div></td><td><button name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" >X</button></td></tr>');
CKEDITOR.replace('desc'+i);
  i++;

});


$(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.2/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<button id="add">ADD</button>
<div id="dynamic_fields"></div>
```